# Infer finite group order by order of elements.

Tags: group-theory

Can I use Sylow's Theorem to determine the order of a group given the order of elements?

For example, Say I have a finite group $G$ that has elements of order 1 through 10.  What is the smallest possible order of $G$?

Also, can my example even exist?  Like is there a group that follows my example of having elements of order 1 through 10?

Comment: What you ask in your first line is different from what you ask in your third line. One thing is **the** order of a group, and nother *the smallest* possible order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any subgroup of G must divide the order of G. So, if you have elements of order 1 through 10, then the order of each must divide the order of G. Hence, the smallest order of G is the least common multiple of 1 through 10.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem says that the order of the subgroup of G must divide the order of G.  How are you applying this to the elements of the subgroup?

Comment: The order of an element is the same as the order of the subgroup that it generates.

Answer (score 0):

For example the group (with $\;C_n:=\;$ the *cyclic* group of order $\;n$):

$$C_8\times C_9\times C_5\times C_7$$

is a group of order $\;8\cdot9\cdot5\cdot7=2,520\;$ with elements of order $\;1,2,3...,9,10\;$

Comment: Can you please explain further?